# Using decorator and strategy pattern for dynamically generating SQL queries

Tags: java, sql, design-patterns, swing

[image: This part of the application design deals with generating sql query strings dynamically]
[image: This is the entire detailed architecture of the application]

[This is a link to my application that actually runs on the design specified in the image.](https://tinyurl.com/minissms)

The idea behind the image is that the `SubjectInfoViewer` behaves as the context in the strategy pattern, and the `ViewingQueryComponent` behaves as the strategy interface, as well as the component class in the decorator pattern, and its implementing classes except the Filter class are the different strategies. These strategies return an SQL string specific to their description, which can be decorated using the Filter class, which is the decorator, in the decorator pattern. The classes implementing the filter class just append the where clause of the SQL string produced by the strategies and push the parameters involved in the where clause in a parameter stack, so they can finally by used by a parameterized SQL statement involving the whole "stitched" SQL string.

For some reason, this doesn't seem to be the right approach to tackle this particular usecase. Please suggest the best practices used in this situation.

The reason this doesn't seem to be the right approach is that there are a lot of tables being joined in the base queries, just for the convenience of writing where clauses in the Filters.

I really would like to reduce the accidental complexity of having to push the parameters used in where clauses into the `paramStack` for using them in a parameterized query and having to call all the filters only for some filters to do nothing but by pass the call to another filter without doing anything useful.

By the way, the repeated code in the base queries can be easily abstracted..
Also, better decoupling can be ensured by isolating the `UserInterface` reference to the `SubjectInfoViewer` so that it passes the parameters it receives from the getters of the `UserInterace` to the Filters, instead of having the Filters get them from the `UserInterface`.

**SubjectInfoViewer.java**

```
public class SubjectInfoViewer {
    private ViewingQueryComponent baseQuery;
    private ViewingQueryComponent vqc;
    private String viewingQuery;
    private Stack<String> viewParams=new Stack<>();
    private UserInterface ui;

    public void changeBaseQuery(ViewingQueryComponent vqc){
        baseQuery=vqc;
    }
    public void stitch(){
            vqc=new COFilter(ui,viewParams,
            new USNFilter(ui,viewParams,
            new DifficultyFilter(ui,viewParams,
            new SectionFilter(ui,viewParams,
            new DateFilter(ui,viewParams,
            new ModuleFilter(ui,viewParams,
            new SubjectFilter(ui,viewParams,
            baseQuery)))))));
            viewingQuery=vqc.stitch()+" GROUP BY STATUS.Topic_Name,QUESTION_BANK.Question_Statement";    
    }
    public SubjectInfoViewer(UserInterface ui) {
        this.ui=ui;
        baseQuery=new DefaultViewingQuery();
    }
    public DefaultTableModel getTableModel() {
         return new DBGateway().getSubjectDetails(viewingQuery,viewParams);
    }
}
```

**ViewingQueryComponent.java**

```
public interface ViewingQueryComponent {

String stitch();}
```

**DefaultViewingQuery.java**

```
public class DefaultViewingQuery implements ViewingQueryComponent {
private String  sql=  
                "SELECT "
                + "TOPICS.Topic_Name AS \"Topic Name\", "
                + "TOPICS.Textbook_Name AS \"Textbook Name\", "
                + "TOPICS.Page_Number AS \"Page Number\", "
                + "MADE_FROM.Question_Statement AS \"Question Statement\", "
                + "QUESTION_BANK.Total_Marks AS \"Total Marks\", "
                + "ROUND((COUNT(DISTINCT STATUS.USN)/(SELECT SUM(STUDENT.USN) FROM STUDENT))*100,2) AS \"Total Students (%)\" "
                + "FROM "
                + "STATUS, "
                + "TEXTBOOK, "
                + "SUBJECT, "
                + "STUDENT, "
                + "DISTRIBUTE, "
                + "TOPICS LEFT JOIN (MADE_FROM,QUESTION_BANK) ON TOPICS.Topic_Name = MADE_FROM.Topic_Name AND QUESTION_BANK.Question_Statement=MADE_FROM.Question_Statement "
                + "WHERE "
                + "DISTRIBUTE.Topic_Name=TOPICS.Topic_Name and "
                + "TEXTBOOK.Textbook_Name=TOPICS.Textbook_Name and "
                + "STATUS.Topic_Name=TOPICS.Topic_Name and "
                + "STATUS.USN=STUDENT.USN ";

@Override
public String stitch() {
    return sql;
}}
```

**SectionViewingQuery.java**

```
public class SectionViewingQuery implements ViewingQueryComponent{
private String  sql;
public SectionViewingQuery(UserInterface ui){
    sql=        "SELECT "
                + "TOPICS.Topic_Name AS \"Topic Name\", "
                + "TOPICS.Textbook_Name AS \"Textbook Name\", "
                + "TOPICS.Page_Number AS \"Page Number\", "
                + "MADE_FROM.Question_Statement AS \"Question Statement\", "
                + "QUESTION_BANK.Total_Marks AS \"Total Marks\", "
                + "(COUNT(DISTINCT STATUS.USN)/(SELECT SUM(STUDENT.USN) FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT.Section=\""+ui.getSection()+"\"))*100 AS \"Total Students (%)\" "
                + "FROM "
                + "STATUS, "
                + "TEXTBOOK, "
                + "SUBJECT, "
                + "STUDENT, "
                + "DISTRIBUTE, "
                + "TOPICS LEFT JOIN (MADE_FROM,QUESTION_BANK) ON TOPICS.Topic_Name = MADE_FROM.Topic_Name AND QUESTION_BANK.Question_Statement=MADE_FROM.Question_Statement "
                + "WHERE "
                + "DISTRIBUTE.Topic_Name=TOPICS.Topic_Name and "
                + "TEXTBOOK.Textbook_Name=TOPICS.Textbook_Name and "
                + "STATUS.Topic_Name=TOPICS.Topic_Name and "
                + "STATUS.USN=STUDENT.USN ";
}
@Override
public String stitch() {
    return sql;
}}
```

**Filter.java**

```
public abstract class Filter implements ViewingQueryComponent {

private ViewingQueryComponent vqc;
protected Stack<String> paramStack;

protected String sql="";

abstract boolean setSql();

Filter(ViewingQueryComponent vqc,Stack<String> paramStack){
    this.paramStack=paramStack;
    this.vqc=vqc;
}

@Override
public String stitch(){
    if(setSql())
        return vqc.stitch()+" and "+sql;
    return vqc.stitch()+sql;
}}
```

**SubjectFilter.java**

```
public class SubjectFilter extends Filter{
String subject;
public SubjectFilter(UserInterface ui,Stack<String> paramStack,ViewingQueryComponent vqc) {
    super(vqc,paramStack);
    subject=ui.getSubject();
}

@Override
boolean setSql() {
    if(!CheckHelper.checkEmpty(subject)){
        sql=" TEXTBOOK.Subject_Name=? ";
        paramStack.push(subject);
        return true;
    }return false;
}}
```

Comment: Hello @Muhammed. This is the kind of questions that you should ask on stackoverflow, not codereview (because there is not code to review). But you should explain why _"this doesn't seem to be the right approach"_

Comment: Hi @gervais.b I have updated the question to reflect the suggestions made. Thank you. And regarding the explanation of why this doesn't seem to be the right approach, It is because of the awkwardness of pushing parameters used in the where clause into a stack to be later used in the parameterized sql query.

Comment: let me know if anyone needs more code to help them better review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some names a bit more obvious with respect to their purpose.

The inconvenience of using a parameter stack can be overcome, by creating a class `ViewingQuery` which encapsulates the sql query as well as its parameters.

This could be instantiated as an immutable object, which gets transformed by the `ViewingQueryComponent`s' `composeViewingQuery()` method.

The guard condition can be implemented within the `ViewingQuery` class.

An object of the `ViewingQuery` class named `compositeViewingQuery` shall be composed in the `SubjectInfoViewer` class.

The `composeViewingQuery()` in the `SubjectInfoViewer` shall transform the `ViewingQuery` and assign it to `compositeViewingQuery`

Although this approach provides nice abstraction and better adheres to the single responsibility principle, it has an accidental complexity built into it.

The accidental complexity is that, `getViewTableModel()` is dependent on the state changed by `composeViewingQuery()`. Hence the sequence of invocation of these methods becomes important.

One way to overcome this accidental complexity, is by making the `composeViewingQuery()` method in the `SubjectInfoViewer` private, and calling it from `getViewTableModel()` and removing the attribute `compositeViewingQuery` at the cost of violating single responsibility principle. This move would also make testing hard.

Another way to overcome this accidental complexity, is by having the `composeViewingQuery()` method of `SubjectInfoViewer` return the compositeViewingQuery. Then remove the `getViewTableModel` method. This way, the client directly calls the `getSubjectDetails` method of DBGateway by passing the value returned from `composeViewingQuery`. This may be the best approach.

Also, the current solution can be improved by passing an instance of `ViewingQuery` as a parameter for `composeViewingQuery()` in order to improve readability.

The following is the refactored code:

**ViewingQuery.java**

```
public class ViewingQuery {
    
    private final List<String> parameterList;
    private final String baseQuery;
    private final String queryFilters;
    
    ViewingQuery(){
        parameterList=new ArrayList<>();
        baseQuery="";
        queryFilters="";
    }
    ViewingQuery(List parameterList,String queryFilter,String baseQuery){
        this.parameterList=parameterList;
        this.baseQuery=baseQuery;
        this.queryFilters=queryFilter;
    }
    
    public ViewingQuery withFilter(String queryFilter,String ... parameters){
        if(!CheckHelper.checkEmpty(parameters)){
            List<String> newParameterList=getNewParameterList(parameters);
            return new ViewingQuery(newParameterList,this.queryFilters+" and "+queryFilter,this.baseQuery);
        }
        return this;
    }

    private List<String> getNewParameterList(String[] parameters) {
        List<String> newParameterList=new ArrayList<>();
        newParameterList.addAll(this.parameterList);
        newParameterList.addAll(Arrays.asList(parameters));
        return newParameterList;
    }
    public ViewingQuery withBaseQuery(String baseQuery,String ... parameters){
        List<String> newParameterList=getNewParameterList(parameters);
        return new ViewingQuery(newParameterList,this.queryFilters,baseQuery);
    }   
    public String getQuery(){
        if(CheckHelper.checkEmpty(baseQuery))
            return "";
        return baseQuery+queryFilters+" GROUP BY STATUS.Topic_Name,QUESTION_BANK.Question_Statement";
    }
    public List<String> getParameterList(){
        return parameterList;
    }
}
```

**SubjectInfoViewer.java**

```
public class SubjectInfoViewer {
    private ViewingQueryComponent baseQueryComponent;
    private final UserInterface ui;
    
    public SubjectInfoViewer(UserInterface ui) {
        this.ui=ui;
        baseQueryComponent=new DefaultViewingQuery();
    }    
    
    public void changeBaseQueryComponent(ViewingQueryComponent baseQueryComponent){
        this.baseQueryComponent=baseQueryComponent;
    }
    public ViewingQuery composeViewingQuery(){
        return  new COFilter(ui.getCO(), 
                new USNFilter(ui.getUSN(), 
                new DifficultyFilter(ui.getDifficulty(), 
                new SectionFilter(ui.getSection(), 
                new DateFilter(ui.getInitialDate(),ui.getFinalDate(), 
                new ModuleFilter(ui.getModule(), 
                new SubjectFilter(ui.getSubject(), 
                baseQueryComponent))))))).composeViewingQuery();    
    }
}
```

**ViewingQueryComponent.java**

```
public interface ViewingQueryComponent {
    
    ViewingQuery composeViewingQuery();
}
```

**DefaultViewingQuery.java**

```
public class DefaultViewingQuery implements ViewingQueryComponent {
    private String  sql=  
                    "SELECT "
                    + "TOPICS.Topic_Name AS \"Topic Name\", "
                    + "TOPICS.Textbook_Name AS \"Textbook Name\", "
                    + "TOPICS.Page_Number AS \"Page Number\", "
                    + "MADE_FROM.Question_Statement AS \"Question Statement\", "
                    + "QUESTION_BANK.Total_Marks AS \"Total Marks\", "
                    + "ROUND((COUNT(DISTINCT STATUS.USN)/(SELECT SUM(STUDENT.USN) FROM STUDENT))*100,2) AS \"Total Students (%)\" "
                    + "FROM "
                    + "STATUS, "
                    + "TEXTBOOK, "
                    + "SUBJECT, "
                    + "STUDENT, "
                    + "DISTRIBUTE, "
                    + "TOPICS LEFT JOIN (MADE_FROM,QUESTION_BANK) ON TOPICS.Topic_Name = MADE_FROM.Topic_Name AND QUESTION_BANK.Question_Statement=MADE_FROM.Question_Statement "
                    + "WHERE "
                    + "DISTRIBUTE.Topic_Name=TOPICS.Topic_Name and "
                    + "TEXTBOOK.Textbook_Name=TOPICS.Textbook_Name and "
                    + "STATUS.Topic_Name=TOPICS.Topic_Name and "
                    + "STATUS.USN=STUDENT.USN ";

    @Override
    public ViewingQuery composeViewingQuery() {
        return new ViewingQuery().withBaseQuery(sql);
    } 
}
```

**SectionViewingQuery.java**

```
public class SectionViewingQuery implements ViewingQueryComponent{
    private final String  sql;
    private final String section;
    public SectionViewingQuery(String section){
        this.section=section;
        sql=        "SELECT "
                    + "TOPICS.Topic_Name AS \"Topic Name\", "
                    + "TOPICS.Textbook_Name AS \"Textbook Name\", "
                    + "TOPICS.Page_Number AS \"Page Number\", "
                    + "MADE_FROM.Question_Statement AS \"Question Statement\", "
                    + "QUESTION_BANK.Total_Marks AS \"Total Marks\", "
                    + "(COUNT(DISTINCT STATUS.USN)/(SELECT SUM(STUDENT.USN) FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT.Section=?))*100 AS \"Total Students (%)\" "
                    + "FROM "
                    + "STATUS, "
                    + "TEXTBOOK, "
                    + "SUBJECT, "
                    + "STUDENT, "
                    + "DISTRIBUTE, "
                    + "TOPICS LEFT JOIN (MADE_FROM,QUESTION_BANK) ON TOPICS.Topic_Name = MADE_FROM.Topic_Name AND QUESTION_BANK.Question_Statement=MADE_FROM.Question_Statement "
                    + "WHERE "
                    + "DISTRIBUTE.Topic_Name=TOPICS.Topic_Name and "
                    + "TEXTBOOK.Textbook_Name=TOPICS.Textbook_Name and "
                    + "STATUS.Topic_Name=TOPICS.Topic_Name and "
                    + "STATUS.USN=STUDENT.USN ";
    }
    @Override
    public ViewingQuery composeViewingQuery() {
        return new ViewingQuery().withBaseQuery(sql,section);
    }  
}
```

**Filter.java**

```
public abstract class Filter implements ViewingQueryComponent {

    protected final ViewingQueryComponent vqc;    
    
    Filter(ViewingQueryComponent vqc){    
        this.vqc=vqc;
    }
}
```

**SubjectFilter.java**

```
public class SubjectFilter extends Filter{

    private final String subject;
    private final String sql;

    public SubjectFilter(String subject,ViewingQueryComponent vqc) {
        super(vqc);
        sql="TEXTBOOK.Subject_Name=?";
        this.subject=subject;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewingQuery composeViewingQuery() {
        return vqc.composeViewingQuery().withFilter(sql, subject);
    }
}
```

There's an inherent limitation in using the decorator pattern like this. The limitation is that you cannot selectively remove filters from existing filter chains dynamically, hopefully there might be an ideal solution that preserves the functional nature of the solution while over coming this limitation.

Perhaps the intercepting filter design pattern is more appropriate here instead of the decorator design pattern. Make the `SubjectInfoViewer` the `FilterManager` and implement, for every `Filter` the `hashCode` and `equals` methods as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198019/whats-a-suitable-implementation-of-equals-for-a-class-with-no-fields) as the state of the `Filter`s become irrelevant for every `composeViewingQuery` message passed from the `ui` so they can be easily removed in the `FilterChain`, if implemented as a `Set`.

But this pattern although will provide more flexibility than the decorator, it will need to pass unneeded parameters into the constructors of the filters just to remove the filters from the `FilterChain`. And this solution will possibly be feasible at the expense of sacrificing the declarative nature of the decorator solution

Answer (score 1):

- You've followed the Java naming conventions, but several functions are named within the programming solution domain rather than the business problem domain. Stick to the problem domain when naming.
- Some bits of the code are difficult to follow, the `stitch()` method for example, with all the nested function calls to complete the parameters, you can achieve the same level of flexibility but with a large increase in clarity by using the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Name the methods using the field names from the problem domain.
- Concatenating strings to construct SQL queries looks simple but it can quickly become unmanageable as you've discovered.  It is also extremely dangerous for security being a risk of SQL injections attacks.  **Do not do it**.  Instead use [`PreparedStatements`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) which [works well with the Builder Pattern.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380150/java-create-preparedstatement-with-no-sql-content)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Regarding the first point, isn't it inevitable to have some functions or classes represent the solution instead of the problem domain ?

Comment: As for the second point, thank you for the suggestion. I'll look into it seeking to find a builder solution that follows the open closed principle, like the current solution does. As for the third point, I have actually used `PreparedStatements` in the `DBGateway`. I'm sorry that I haven't made it obvious. but if you look closely at the last snippet's use of `?` you might get a clue. But again, i'll try to see how builder pattern fits here.